# JDBC architecture sub-systems

Tags: java, jdbc, driver

I am trying to understand JDBC technology. I read on-line materials, and most of them talks about:

1) JDBC API

2) DriverManager

3) Driver

I saw the following architecture diagram:

[image: JDBC architecture]

As per JDBC specification, the jdbc related stuff are in java.sql and javax.sql packages. I have following questions:

1) In diagram when we see JDBC API, what exactly are they? Are these the classes/interfaces in java.sql; javax.sql? Are these directly used in the application? who implement JDBC API?

2) Does JDK provide implementation of all classes/interfaces defined in java.sql; javax.sql?

3) Who implements JDBC Driver Manager? Is it provided by JDK itself or provided by Database vendor? Does it run as a process or is it just a class/interface?

4) What exactly is a driver? As I understand a driver communicates to the Database server and are provided by database vendors? Now, do these drivers implement java.sql ; javax.sql? Or do drivers have different classes which are not related to java.sql; javax.sql? Is there any relationship between JDBC API (in above diagram) and the drivers?

Comment: This would be useful: http://bayanbox.ir/view/8722165392691200124/JDBC-diagram.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JDBC API is formed by two packages:

1. java.sql: contains the main classes and interfaces; for example, classes like           Driver, Connection, Statement, ResultSet, PreparedStatement and CallableStatement are included in this package.
2. javax.sql: contains more specific classes like RowSet, DataSource or PooledConnection.

Those packages contain all the classes and interfaces that are needed to access to the data from a db. However they are not sufficient because the classes and interfaces that implement JDBC that allow to connect to different DBMA are missing, so we need a driver.

There are 4 types of drivers in function of the access type:

-Type 1: JDBC-ODBC
-Type 2: JDBC-libDBMA
-Type 3: JDBC - middleware driver (type 1,2,4) - DBMA
-Type 4: JDBC - DBMA (direct)

For do a connection with a java app and a db you have to:
    first load the packages.
    second load the driver.
so to answer your question the JDBC driver is not provided by  JDK itself (download from and other source is necessary) and JDK does not provided implementation of all classes/interfaces defined in java.sql; javax.sq 'cause you have to import them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So it means that DriverManager isn't part of "driver"?  And "driver" implement some  classes/interfaces of javax.sql and java.sql?

Comment: The DriveManager is not part of the choosen_driver is a class in java's API (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) and the driver is a .jar file that you have to add to your IDE.                         In execution time the DriveManager main function is to load the choosen_driver to allow the access to the db and associated to your java app. And for the second question, 'yes' for example, the choosen_driver' implements the interface DRIVER from the package  java.sql.

Answer (score 2):

1. The JDBC API are the classes and interfaces in java.sql and javax.sql.
2. No.
3. The Driver Manager is the class `java.sql.DriverManager` which is part of the JRE/JDK.
4. The drivers implement the interface in java(x).sql. Most important, the driver creates intances of `java.sql.Connection`.